# Bottom wall plate half on parallel joist, safe?

Tags: joists

In replacing a bathroom shower stall, we are replacing a piece of sub flooring with your typical shower damage to it. In replacing it, I noticed the exterior wall which runs parallel to the joist is only half on the joist itself. It went joist, subfloor (part of which is being removed, bottom plate. See illustration attached. Is it safe to be half over the joist with an equal width of old subfloor between it and the joist? Ideally, I'd like to box in a frame between the new joists to support the new subfloor panel, but that would not go under the bottom plate.

[image: Joist with subfloor and bottom plate on it]

Comment: If your joists truly run parallel to the wall then what in the world is the part depicted below? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ahk3.png).